# .htaccess, get, чпу

Tags: php, .htaccess, чпу

Что нужно прописать в htaccess, что бы превратить ссылку

из

```
http://domain/page1/profile?get_par
```

в

```
http://domain/get_par
```

?

Comment: Покажите что у вас там сейчас

Comment: @sanmai https://localhost/php/user?test

Answer (score 0):

апача под рукой нет. для nginx будет так:

```
server {            
        rewrite_log on;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/myerror.log notice;
        rewrite page\d/profile?(.*)$ /$args last;
.....
}
```

Comment: Интересно было бы посмотреть на версию для .htaccess